# Keep EIGRP up even through an interface flaps

Tags: cisco, eigrp

Does EIGRP have a feature similar to disabling fast fallover in BGP, where we can allow a link to flap for a (hopefully definable) period of time and still leave the EIGRP neighborship up?

My understanding is that hold timers mean nothing if the physical link goes down.  The goal here is to prevent exchange storms when older WAN links start flapping/erroring heavily.

Comment: This is not quite what you want, but solving repetitive link flaps should be done with [ip event dampening](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/s_ipevdp.html)

Comment: @MikePennington - this is a very interesting feature!!  There is a ton of potential here for protecting larger edge routers.  In practice is this used much and if so in what scenarios do you see it most commonly?? If you want - I can open a separate topic on this.  With regards to this topic, the answer is: no eigrp doesn't have a feature.  We can leave it open ended or if you want to post a reply I'll accept it as answer.  Thanks as always Mike!  Hope you're doing well!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered setting the link debounce timer to a higher value than its default (which I think is 100ms)? This basically delays the notification that the link has flapped, and can affect reconvergence.